# regular expression to match backslash

Tags: r, regex

In R,

I have the following string: `C:\\Users\\jam\\Downloads\\tomato\\roja.exe`
and the following regular expression: `^(.*\\\\)([^\\\\]*)$`

From this I want the folder path: `C:\\Users\\jam\\Downloads\\tomato\\`

If I do a grep like:

```
grep("^(.*\\\\)([^\\\\]*)$", "C:\\Users\\jam\\Downloads\\tomato\\roja.exe",value=TRUE)
```

I get `C:\\Users\\jam\\Downloads\\tomato\\roja.exe` as a result which is not the expected result.

Any ideas on improving the regular expression?

Comment: How about just `^(.*\\\\)`

Comment: @MElliott nope does not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to use regular expression, try `dirname`:

```
 dirname(" C:\\Users\\jam\\Downloads\\tomato\\roja.exe")
" C:/Users/jam/Downloads/tomato"
```

and `basename`  to get file name:

```
basename(" C:\\Users\\jam\\Downloads\\tomato\\roja.exe")
[1] "roja.exe"
```

**EDIT**

Using regular expression I will use something like this :

```
gsub('(.*)[\\](.*)','\\1' ,"C:\\Users\\jam\\Downloads\\tomato\\roja.exe")
[1] "C:\\Users\\jam\\Downloads\\tomato"

gsub('(.*)[\\](.*)','\\2' ,"C:\\Users\\jam\\Downloads\\tomato\\roja.exe")
[1] "roja.exe"
```

Comment: well that is helpful but does not solve the issue. dirname returns the path with '/' characters on windows which is not valid.

Comment: @wanderer In R, they are valid.

Comment: Thanks @MatthewLundberg. "/" characters in a path on windows works in R.

Comment: but still, as an exercise, I would like to know what exactly is wrong with the my regular expression.

Comment: @wanderer I add a regular expression solution.

Comment: What's wrong with the regular expression is that there is only one backslash character in `"C:\\Users"`.  Try `cat("C:\\Users")` to see.